# Magento 2: shipping checked by default

Tags: magento2

How can we enable this checkbox as standard? Now it is off by default. It concerns the checkbox to send the tracking data directly to the customer by e-mail.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfYAd.png

Comment: Are you talking about the shipment create screen?

Comment: by default checked checkbox

Comment: Yes, its about the shipment create screen. My colleagues forget to tick that, because of this the customer does not receive automatic e-mail. How can we solve that?

Comment: Please check with this - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125070/magento2-make-checkbox-checked-by-default-in-checkout-page